# Model Name With underscore cannot loaded in production environment

Tags: codeigniter-3

i was using CI ver.  2.2.0 for my ongoing projects and now I'm trying to switch to CI 3

The switching process was done successfully in my local environment(XAMPP) and i haven't found any error, but when i upload my project to production, i get an model not found error. "Unable to locate the model you have specified: Model_name ".

The thing is, when i try to load model which name containing underscore(_) CI always show model not found error. When i remove the underscore, CI runs perfectly. I'm not sure this is a bug since it does running fine in my local XAMPP and i have all the controller and model name changed to CI 3 standard.
even i have tried to name the model "Model_Name"

What can i do to fix this problem ?
i already posted this on the official CI forum but, the every post need moderation policy make this slow.

Comment: I use underscores in all my models in my CI 3.0.0 applications without a problem. Could you edit the question to show us the code where you are calling the model? And also include your folder/naming structure? That will help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

change your class model name into `Model_name`. also with filename. it should work